# Child overlaps other element despite having lower z-index?

Tags: css, position, z-index, children

So i've been experimenting with z-index today, and i really do not understand what is happening here.

Here's a very simplified version of the HTML:

```
// content has z-index of 30, pos abs
<div class="content">
    // content-centered has z-index of 32, pos rel
    <div class="content-centered">
        // Text and buttons goes here
    </div>
</div>

// bubbles has z-index of 31, pos abs
<div class="bubbles">
    <div class="bubbles-centered">
        // Bubbles goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to have .content provide the background content, then the bubbles above the background, and at last the content above the bubbles. What is happening is for some reason the bubbles are above the content.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zFFkv/1/

Give it a few seconds for the bubbles to appear over the content. You can't select the text or push the buttons, because the bubble-layer is above the content layer, even though it's set below. What's going on? Does child elements not inherit the parents index?

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe that will be helpfull for You: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/ I didn't read it yet but it's whole article about z-index'es.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-indices are resolved relative to their parent, not the whole document.

`.bubbles` are above `.content`, and that's all that matters in your case. All the children inside `.content` will be below `.bubbles`, but can be ordered relative to each other.

To do what you're trying to do `.content-centered` and `.bubbles` will have to be siblings.

Comment: Well, crap.  That's not really an alternative for me. If you inspected the demo, you'll see that i have several `<segment>`'s in .content, all of which has it's own .content-centered. To put .bubbles inside of .content-centered would mean multiple copies of it, and that's not good. (It also just feels wrong) Are there any work arounds?

Comment: I didn't mean put `.bubbles` inside `.content-centered`, I meant put `.bubbles` inside `.content`. In your simple example that means `.bubbles` can be above `.content` and below `.content-centered`. In the demo, it would mean the bubble container sits alongside the `section`s, and can be underneath them.

Comment: To be more precise, they're relative to their stacking contexts. These contexts are typically created by positioned parents, but not strictly.

Comment: @freejosh See this: http://i.imgur.com/Qbe9h.png. That's how it actually looks like. Think of each `<section>` as `.content`. Each `<section>` has it's own background with a z-index of 30. Since there are multiple sections (think of them as pages), i would have to have multiple copies of .bubbles (one inside every section). What i could do is move the backgrounds out of each segment into a sibling of `#slide-container`, that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can set pointer-events to none to on the bubbles element to prevent it from blocking the links below, although I don't think it has great support in IE.

```
.bubbles {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://robertnyman.com/css3/pointer-events/pointer-events.html)

Comment: That's nice, didn't know about that!